Is there any chance that MOSFET hits under 1 nm scale? I mean can it hit picometer scaling?
As far as I know optical transistors, meaning transistors that would store and work 100% with photons is yet a science fiction. So, CPUs in order to improve their "speed" they need smaller transistors. However, how possible is it to see in the future MOSFET built in picometers? Ok, it is more than obvious that Silicon cannot withstand less than 1 nm, due to its limits. So, in order to have commercial MOSFET under 1 nm is only a thing of inventing new materials or something else?

Node names are just marketing, and anything is possible to a marketer, so of course there will be picometer branded nodes. Current roadmaps put them around the end of this decade.

Well, keep in mind a sense of scale.  Atoms are on the order of 100pm across. There's not much left to "semiconduct" at these scales.  Electrons are quantized as waves rather than pseudo-continuum states, making current flow and voltage levels peculiar (not necessarily worse, but even more dependent on exact geometry).  You don't so much have carrier concentrations, as probabilities of some carriers present or not; and dopant atoms aren't so much a source of carriers, as a modifier of probability (or completely absent from the junction, making yield highly problematic).
At the smallest scales, you have a: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-atom_transistor
It's not likely to be economical to produce, at least for a long time.  It's also possible that alternative fabrication methods are developed, for example making a corner or edge that therefore has different surface energy, and doing targeted chemical reactions on that. Thus breaking the limitations of photolithography.  ...No idea what kind of research is being done along those lines, just open speculation to represent a possibility.
Optics are irrelevant for miniaturization, as wavelengths span thousands of atoms (i.e. 100s nm even within a waveguide, n > 2).  This can still be an acceptable sacrifice for long-distance communication (where the losses can potentially be lower than for wire interconnects, and perhaps the group velocity faster due to lower losses and not needing buffering/repeaters; with low enough losses, quantum entanglement also becomes an option).
